# Does Kreighton's Cognitive Crossover's attempt benefit from one-time effects used on its triggering check?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e

[Kreighton's Cognitive Crossover](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2272) lets a character reattempt a [Recall Knowledge](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=26) check as a reaction. I want to know whether Kreighton's Cognitive Crossover's attempt benefits from effects used on its triggering check. I'm thinking of effects that normally work once, such as a bonus from [*guidance*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=142) or [Aid](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=75), or such as a fortune effect from [*loremaster's etude*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=390) or [Automatic Knowledge](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=757).

For example:

- I attempt a Recall Knowledge check with Arcana, roll twice with *loremaster's etude*, and apply the bonuses from an ally's *guidance* and Aid, but fail anyway. So when I reattempt with Society using Kreighton's Cognitive Crossover, do I still roll twice and apply those bonuses?
- I attempt a Recall Knowledge check with Arcana and forgo the roll with Automatic Knowledge, but fail. So when I reattempt with Society using Kreighton's Cognitive Crossover, do I still forgo rolling to take 10+proficiency?

When I learned about Kreighton's Cognitive Crossover feat, it never occurred to me that these one-time effects could carry over and benefit both the triggering check and the Crossover attempt, but I've recently met with a player who believes they do. Honestly, I don't see it, but maybe I don't see it right now *because I am biased*: I'm currently playing a mastermind rogue who relies a lot on Assurance *not* carrying over from Automatic Knowledge's attempt to Kreighton's Cognitive Crossover's attempt.

Comment: That's tricky. I'm not sure if there are any other instances where you "reattempt" a check.

Answer (score 6):

### This is an unclear area of the rules. In my view, you'd treat them as distinct checks.

Based on an Archives of Nethys search, Kreighton's Cognitive Crossover is the only rules item (feat, feature, ability, spell, etc.) that uses the term "reattempt." Because of that, it's hard to say how exactly the rules are supposed to be enforced here, and you should check with your GM to see how it will be enforced at the table.

Personally, I think it makes more sense for both checks to be distinct from each other. Effectively, what "reattempt the triggering check" means in my view is "take the same action (Recall Knowledge) a second time." That means that effects that only occur once, like the circumstance bonus from Aid or the status bonus from Guidance, wouldn't apply to the second check.

Fortune effects like Automatic Knowledge and Loremaster's Etude could be used on the second check, but their use wouldn't be mandatory. You'd decide whether or not to use them when you make the second check.

However, as a GM, I'd also give myself leeway to adjust the DC of the second check if the crossover skill isn't as relevant. For example, if you failed a Nature check to recall knowledge about an animal, I'd let you crossover into Medicine, but I'd rule that the DC for using Medicine would be at a Hard DC (+2).

Comment: I have to agree with this for a specific reason, which is not included here, Cognitive Crossover does not have the Fortune trait typical of other 'reroll' options.